# MVC 4 Entity Framework Model is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have This Code in my Truck Controller, every time i run it.

My model is always null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTruck(TruckDataModel model)
    {
        var newTruck = new truck()
        {
            registration_no = model.reg_no,
            make = model.make,
            model = model.model,
            engine_no = model.engine_no,
            chassis_no = model.chassis_no,
            driver_name = model.driver_name,
            driver_no = model.driver_no,
            current_run = model.current_run,

        };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.trucks.Add(newTruck);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("TruckList","Trucks");
        }

        return View(model);
```

This is my model

```
public class TruckDataModel
{         
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Registration No. required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Registration No.")]
    public string reg_no { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Make required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Make")]
    public string make { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Model required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public string model { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Engine No. required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Engine No.")]
    public string engine_no { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Chassis No. required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Chassis No.")]
    public string chassis_no { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Driver Name required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Driver Name")]
    public string driver_name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Current Run required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Current Run")]
    public int current_run { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Driver no. required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Driver No.")]
    public int driver_no { get; set; }


}//just for allow to edit
```

I have the exception NullReference always occur, and when I breakpoint, the all the model is null.

I have the exact code in my CreateUser Action but it works perfectly fine?
Please need help TY SO MUCH!!

Comment: provide your code of `View` from where this Post action occur

Comment: @Sac, the view is not necessary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TruckDataModel` model has a property named `model` and your POST method parameter is also named `model`. You need to change one or the other, say

```
public ActionResult AddTruck(TruckDataModel truck)
{
  ....
}
```

The reason is that the `DefautModelBinder` first initializes an instance of `TruckDataModel`. It then reads the form data, sees a name/value pair for `model`, then tries to set your parameter to its value (to say `model="Ford"`) which fails and so the model becomes `null`

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me very much